# ExtJs 4.2 Paging toolbar - Disable invalid page message

Tags: extjs4.2, pagingtoolbar

I have set up a paging toolbar for my grid. If I put an invalid number in the text field for page numbers, an error message/quicktip is displayed. I want to disable it. I have gone through all the configs, but couldn't find one. Is there a way to do this?

[Try here!](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/grid/paging/)

Try adding a 0 in the text input for the paging toolbar, and keep pointing at it with the mouse. The tooltip will pop out.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle, cause I never see this message, invalid values are rounded to the max/min page in my apps

Comment: Oops no fiddle! Wait let me get there example page link

Comment: Here: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/grid/paging/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `getPagingItems` function for this:

```
xtype: 'gridpanel',
(...),
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    (...),
    getPagingItems: function() {
        var me = this;
        var pagingItems = me.self.prototype.getPagingItems.apply(me, arguments);
        for (var i in pagingItems) {
            var pagingItem = pagingItems[i];
            if (pagingItem != null && pagingItem.itemId == 'inputItem') {
                pagingItem.preventMark = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return pagingItems;
    }
}]
```

Comment: Hurray! You rock! Thanks! :)